# Reverse-Engineer SQL Server Compact Edition database using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server-ce, entity-framework-5

Can we "reverse engineer" a SQLCE (SQL Server Compact Edition) database using Entity Framework?

I've followed the MSDN Development Center tutorial *[Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620)* on using the Entity Framework to "reverse engineer" a database so that we can use code-first with it. As per the tutorial I've:

1. Installed the  *[Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)*.
2. Generated an application (Empty MVC4) in Visual Studio 2012.
3. Added a database (I need to use SQLCE).
4. Right-clicked the root project folder and selected `Entity Framework > Reverse Engineer Code First`.
5. When the Connection Properties window pops up I changed the DataSource type to 'Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0.
6. Browse to the Project App_Data folder and select the SQLCE database.
7. Test the connection (success) and click Ok.

Then the following error is thrown:

```
System.ArgumentException: 
The modelEntityContainerName parameter '...\App_Data\cesdfContext' contains characters that are not valid.
```

Comment: It is a known issue, will be fixed in EF6: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed  by following ***[the link provided in the comment](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/366)*** (by (thanks and credit to(ErikEJ)) to my original post that this issue is to be fixed in the Entity Framework 6 release.